# Copying Files to a directory at regular/specified intervals

Tags: windows, automation

You guys are my last resort as I was certain this would be an easy solve, but i'm out of ideas so any assistance really appreciated.

**THE PROBLEM**

1) I wish to move individual files across at either regular or specified intervals to another directory.
2) Also when a file is moved over the datestamp has to be set to current.

**MY ATTEMPTS**

I first tried *Dropit*, which seemed to be what I needed in terms of automation, however I can't find any means of scheduling the tasks. With some more research I then installed *Advanced Task Scheduler*, which seemed to have all the answers until i got stuck. As now I had advanced scheduling options, however on testing it the only move/copy functions seemed to move an entire folders worth of files in one go.  I didn't see an option for individual files, but just directories which was frustrating.

As for changing the timestamp, I wanted to use the unix 'touch' operand. I went from moving, to copying a file over if that helped in changing the datestamp - which it didn't. It exactly copied over the datestamp from the original - however found this which was really useful :

```
 http://superuser.com/questions/292630/how-can-i-change-the-timestamp-on-a-file
```

This is all well and good, but I've not managed to achieve the main objective.  I really need this done, so anybody can point me in the right directopm, i'd appreciate that.

Comment: have you tried doing  this on a separate thread with a specified delay ?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your timestamp part of the question but the job could be done using cmd. Here is the code.

```
:loop
xcopy d:\source "C:\destination" /E /D /Y
timeout (seconds for interval)
goto loop
```

Hope I helped.

Edit:

```
xcopy d:\source "C:\destination" /E /Y
```

Its the code for all files with your timestamp thing but every time every file will be replaced.

Comment: Awesome, lemme try this. How do i execute the block in .bat file? RE: timestamp. All that i want is the newly copied files to be set to the new current time & date.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately - first execution it copies the whole directory (i.e every file) and then waits for the timeout section.

Comment: Brother that is so because it copies only new files or old files that have been modified.
But I got your desire.
You need this code.

`xcopy d:\source "C:\destination" /E  /Y`
Note: Removed /D